# How to create a clickable local hyperlink opening a word document on a plotly timeline with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I am using Python 3 on Jupyter. I am creating a PDF timeline with Plotly as follows :

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame([
    {"filename": 'blablabla', "start": '1795-01-01', "end": '1810-01-01'},
    {"filename": "Sense and Sensibility","start": '1792-01-01', "end": '1797-01-01'},
    {"filename": "Call the Midwife", "start": '1957-01-01', "end": '1967-02-01'}, 
])

source['start'] = pd.to_datetime(source['start'])
source['end'] = pd.to_datetime(source['end'])
 
fig = px.timeline(source.sort_values('start'),
                  x_start="start",
                  x_end="end",
                  y="filename",
                  text="filename",
                  color_discrete_sequence=["tan"])
fig.show()

fig.write_image("C://Users/mytimeline.pdf")
```

I have no difficulties to create my timeline and to export it in PDF. However, I would like to transform filenames into clickable hyperlinks, each link should open a Word document stored on my computer.

I have tried replacing every filename with a hyperlink like this one :

`<a href="file local link">Link text</a>`

```
{"filename": '<a href=".1CL.docx">Call the Midwife</a>', "start": '1957-01-01', "end": '1967-02-01'}
```

The filename appears blue like a link when I preview my timeline on Jupyter but it opens a new tab on google and let a message of error when I click. And when I transform my timeline in a PDF, the filename isn't even blue anymore, and there is no more link to click.

And if I put the entire file local link (C://Users ... 1CL.docx), Jupyter doesn't even open a new tab in Google.

I don't know what to try next. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Please refer to the community for [examples](https://community.plotly.com/t/hyperlink-to-markers-on-map/17858?u=jmmease) of behavior similar to what you would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting you link to the local file like this:

```
<a href="file:///C:\Path\To\File.docx">Link text</a>
```

If it then doesn't work straight to PDF export, you could try exporting the px graph to HTML and then use a different package to convert HTML to Python.

Answer (score 0):

A PDF can carry a link to open any file but you cannot decide what it may do, here one file link, in 3 viewers, thus the method is not recommended for DocX files, bad enough that it launches another PDF file or one of unknown types.

[image]

- Edge will simply ignore the insecure request to run an external File
- Current SumatraPDF has no idea what that link should do as it has no DocX ability
- Acrobat offers to launch WinWord for you, if you accept the Risk that the link could launch anything, just as if you clicked it yourself.

If you try to give a Fully Qualified URL then Secure Edge and Secure SumatraPDF will simply ignore it however Acrobat will allow you to run it if you trust it.
Thus the answer is generate links designed for Acrobat test only.

[image]